# Can I disable a cylinder on my 2009 Ford Ranger?

Tags: engine, ford, misfire, ranger

This is sort of a hypothetical at this point - I have a misfiring cylinder on my 2009 Ford Ranger 2.3L 4 cylinder engine. I'm trying to diagnose it, but am sort of preparing myself for the possibility that it could be a problem that I'm not able to address ie. something requiring an engine overhaul.

I am getting consistent code 0302 - cylinder 2 misfire errors.

If it turns out that I can't fix the underlying problem, can I just disable the cylinder?Maybe by disconnecting the spark plug and fuel injector? I'd like to continue using the vehicle for short local trips. Obviously this isn't a long-term play, but is it reasonable to think it could get me through the winter?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to disable the cylinder is to pull the connector on the fuel injector. This will prevent fuel from entering the cylinder and then there is no way for excess fuel to build up. The spark plug will continue to fire (if it already firing), but that's not a big deal. The ignition system will just continue to spark it with no damage whatsoever.

Comment: Okay, I'll try this. Perhaps it will answer my other question too, about whether the ECM is disabling the cylinder due to frequent misfires.